# How to disable mouse power status in indicator-power?

Tags: mouse, indicator

Today I have updated to Ubuntu 13.10 and got mouse power status.

But I didn't need it. And also Ubuntu doesn't know how long the mouse will work and shows   an ugly "estimating...".

How do you show only the battery status?

Comment: Do you have `laptop-mode-tools` or `powertop` packages installed?

Comment: No one of them.

Comment: The "estimating" is sure irritating, but Ubuntu does know how much % is remaining. I switched the battery on the wireless mouse and it showed a different %. It seems to be someone's extra-smart idea to show the word "estimating." It should be removed, because there really is no way to estimate how much time would remain for the mouse battery. When I first saw this indicator, it used to show only the battery status like (1:29,94%) but during some update, the indicator changed, and now shows only mouse battery % when on AC and shows only laptop battery % when not on AC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the same issue. It is already reported, you can follow it on :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1234458

Answer (score 8):

There does not appear to be anyway to remove the mouse from the power indicator menu using the built-in configuration options.

What you can do though is select the indicator icon and clear "Show time in the menu bar..."

It is not really the solution any of us want but it does remove the ugly "estimating..."

Answer (score 4):

I also got annoyed at this, and coded up a patch that introduces a configuration setting and a status menu alternative to tell indicator-power to prefer showing the laptop battery, even if there is a mouse or keyboard discharging at the moment.

You can find the code over in this branch for Ubuntu 13.10:

https://code.launchpad.net/~peter-liljenberg/indicator-power/prefer-battery-1100546

It might need a proper bug report to be picked up as a candidate for future versions of indicator-power - I'm not sure how that works at all.

Comment: Could you [edit] the answer to include the code in this answer itself and also mention how can we use that? Keep the link for launchpad so that if you make any further revisions, one may use that instead.

Comment: @petli besides getting the branch, what else do we need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no solution, this indicator use command

```
upower -d
```

to enumerate device. I look with dconf-editor but nothing in /org/freedesktop/upower

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this is a solution or not but try this,

Setting --> Power -->

Show battery status --> change it to When battery is charging/in use[image]

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing / re-inserting your mouse nano receiver. That helped me !

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1: Go to **System Settings** --> **Power**  --> **Show battery status in the menu bar** (change to: *When battery is charging/in use*)

2: Unplug the USB receiver and plug it back in.