# How do I remove the mouse icon from the xfce panel?

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, panel

I do not think this is a duplicate of [How to disable mouse power status in indicator-power?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361022/how-to-disable-mouse-power-status-in-indicator-power), which deals with the Unity panel rather than the xfce panel.

I recently purchased a new wireless mouse to replace my previous wired one. In my notification area, there is now a mouse icon.

[image]

I do not want this icon there, and besides, it appears to serve no useful purpose. Nothing appears when I hover over it or left-click on it. When I right-click on it, the battery monitor menu appears.

The application is not listed in the notification area settings, and changing the "when to show battery icon" settings had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it might even be in the "Indicator Plugin" if not the "Notification area". Did you check the settings for both of those, and the settings for anything else that shows up in the Panel Preferences Items near there, like the battery monitor? You might be able to hide it if it's hiding in another (adjacent?) Panel Item.

Comment: Yes, I checked those settings. It is definitely in the Notification Area; a frame appears around it when I choose to show a frame around the Notification Area. All I discovered was that if I choose to hide the battery indicator, the mouse icon disappears with it, indicating that they are linked.

Comment: I don't have a battery or wireless mouse, so can't do much testing. It's too bad the xfce4-power-manager (I think that's what controls the icons) doesn't have a setting to disable just the mouse, it's all-or-nothing system tray icons. Tried updating xfce4-power-manager? Try looking for bug reports on the xfce4-power-manager and mouse icons? A last resort could be to dig through the xfce4-power-manager source code for any wireless mouse stuff...