# Make systray battery icon turn red when battery low

Tags: keyboard, mouse, power-management, battery, system-tray

#### April 14, 2018 update

Seemingly the problem went away on it's own:

[image: battery red when mouse low]

`power -d` relevant snippet:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_0003o046Do2010x0009
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:2010.0009
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                K800
  serial:               6DB54BFE
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sat 14 Apr 2018 05:26:41 PM MDT (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          20%
    icon-name:          'battery-low-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_0003o046Do101Ax0008
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:101A.0008
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                Performance MX
  serial:               E6CE4571
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sat 14 Apr 2018 05:26:40 PM MDT (28 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          20%
    icon-name:          'battery-low-symbolic'
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
4.14.27-041427-generic
```

Looking back at boot logs based on question date reveals a different kernel version (4.14.23):

```
$ journalctl --list-boots
-23 e9eef9c57f3543d09223d720290e0c4b Tue 2018-03-27 16:47:13 MDT—Tue 2018-03-27 17:16:48 MDT
-22 77c66f077f0e47a5b63f96d0e26fa9da Tue 2018-03-27 17:17:52 MDT—Fri 2018-03-30 11:17:30 MDT
-21 320ccedf358b4aba8b4786a1bec35b96 Fri 2018-03-30 11:52:18 MDT—Fri 2018-03-30 16:29:28 MDT
-20 d80a4dfc777b41fe86ae6f32c9a29aa1 Sat 2018-03-31 08:45:57 MDT—Sun 2018-04-01 10:18:56 MDT

$journalctl -b-22
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-03-05 05:53:18 MST, end at Sat 2018-04-14 17:30:05 MDT. --
Mar 27 17:17:52 alien systemd-journald[295]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/) is 8.0M, ma
Mar 27 17:17:52 alien kernel: Linux version 4.14.23-041423-generic (kernel@kathleen) (gcc ve
Mar 27 17:17:52 alien kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.23-041423-generic
```

---

I'm looking for the reverse of this question where they want to turn off red battery icon on the System Tray: [How to disable mouse power status in indicator-power?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361022/how-to-disable-mouse-power-status-in-indicator-power?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

My System Tray (Application Indicator) icon doesn't turn red when battery runs low on keyboard or mouse:

[image: Power systray doesn't show red keyboard and mouse.png]

I have to rely on keyboard LED turning red when battery is about to die or manually check **Power Statistics** panel (displayed above).

The systray icon used to change to red when mouse or keyboard battery was running low (20%) when attached to old laptop; Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE w/Ivybridge i-7 3630QM. It's never worked on the new laptop; Dell Alienware 17R3 w/Skylake i-7 6700HQ.

Possibly related, the mouse and keyboard never showed up in **Power Statistics** panel at all until I forced driver reload during boot: [Logitech Performance MX mouse shows as "unknown" in Power Statistics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991148/logitech-performance-mx-mouse-shows-as-unknown-in-power-statistics/991155#991155)

#### Any ideas how to make Systray battery icon turn red when mouse or keyboard battery runs low?

---

#### Relevant details

`upower -d` snippets (after batteries were recharged):

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_0003o046Do101Ax0008
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:101A.0008
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                Performance MX
  serial:               E6CE4571
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 28 Mar 2018 05:28:08 PM MDT (106 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          90%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_0003o046Do2010x0009
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:2010.0009
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                K800
  serial:               6DB54BFE
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 28 Mar 2018 05:28:08 PM MDT (106 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          90%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
```

Relevant `gsettings` probably only apply to main battery. ie I would be surprised if laptop suspended whilst main battery was 100% but mouse battery died:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical
3
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action
2
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy
false
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low
10
```